# How to make a matrix from a single line input without using libraries in Python?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I need to make a square matrix of size M*M (which is an user input value) and after that, I should make a matrix out of a line of space-seperated numbers.

```
sizeOfMatrix = int(input())
matrix_input = input()
matrix = [[]*3]*3
for i in range(sizeOfMatrix):
    for j in range (sizeOfMatrix):
    # And this is where I got stuck
        matrix[i][j].append()
```

Comment: And thanks to all in advance those who spend their time in solving this problem...

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and expected output first? For example, if the sizeOfMatrix is 9, what's the `matrix_input` for?   it seems that it never got used?

Comment: @Daniel Hao and others, matrix_input() is a single line input of a matrix, like
matrix_input = "2 37 18 34 23 9 65 4 78" (in case of sizeOfMatrix = 3)... Now, I want to seperate each variable into 3 parts and append them into the variable matrix of type list.

Comment: Does any of these posts help you?

Answer (score 2):

You could try this - it's following original PO, but don't need two loops.
[Notes] it's based on the sample input as PO indicated - collect the matrix_input **(numbers)** in one line (as the Problem Title says).

```
size  = int(input('Enter the size of this Square Matrix: '))  # eg. 3; R == C
numbers = list(map(int, input(f' Enter {size*size} numbers: ').split()))  # all 3x3 numbers 

matrix = []        # [[]*3]*3

for i in range(0, len(numbers), size):
    matrix.append(numbers[i: i+size]) 

print(matrix)
```

Running interactively and Output:

```
Enter the size of this Square Matrix: 3
Enter 9 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Or goes with fancier one-line for this Square Matrix:

```
M = []
while not M or len(M) < len(M[0]):
    M.append(list(map(int,  input('Enter the number for a row: ').split())))
```

Running:

```
Enter the number for a row: 1 2 3
Enter the number for a row: 4 5 6
Enter the number for a row: 7 8 9
>>> M
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a Square Matrix.

```py
sizeOfMatrix = int(input('Matrix Size: '))
mat = []

for i in range(sizeOfMatrix):
    rows = list(map(int, input('Enter space separated values: ').split()))[:sizeOfMatrix]
    mat.append(rows)

print(f'\nMatrix:')
for i in mat:
    print(*i)
```

```
Matrix Size: 3
Enter space separated values: 2 1 6
Enter space separated values: 0 21 8
Enter space separated values: 6 9 7

Matrix:
2 1 6
0 21 8
6 9 7
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but see the new comments made on the issue.

Comment: Update your answer accordingly. Your question is still unclear.

Comment: The PO indicated it collected all numbers input in one step?

Answer (score 0):

if you want  square matrix  make R=C

```
R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:")) 
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:")) 
  
# Initialize matrix 
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 
  
# For user input 
for i in range(R):          # A for loop for row entries 
    a =[] 
    for j in range(C):      # A for loop for column entries 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    matrix.append(a)
```

## For printing the matrix

```
for i in range(R): 
    for j in range(C): 
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but see the new comments made on the issue.

Comment: By definition, in Square Matrix, R == C.  You should just ask one `input`.

Answer (score 0):

For a General N*M Matrix
'''

```
n= int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
m = int(input('Enter the number of columns: '))
input_line = input()
values_str = input_line.split()
matrix = [[int(values_str[j + i * m]) for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]
print(matrix)
```

'''
For a Square Matrix(M*M)

m(rows)=n(columns)